# Unable to see Fedora 20, when triple booting it with Debian 7, and openSuSe 13.1

Tags: linux, debian, fedora, boot, opensuse

I just don't understand why I cannot see my Fedora 20 having it planned to triple boot it with Debian 7 and openSuSe 13.1.

Initially I partitioned my system to:
/dev/sda1 for openSuSe 13.1
/dev/sda2 for Debian 7
/dev/sda3 for Fedora 20
/dev/sda4 for swap

The sequence of my installations are as follows:

1. Install Debian 7.
2. Install Fedora 20.

I just checked if this works, and it worked out OK so I continue installing 
Fedora 20 (step 3).

But, when I boot, the bootloader cannot find "Fedora 20". It just displayed Debian and openSuSe as choices.

Comment: Which bootloader are you using? From which OS? You may not have installed os-prober.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing Fedora first and then Debian. Debian usually plays well with others, as long as it the last kid picked.